# Conway polynomial of the unknot

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I was trying to follow along with Wikipedia's basic computation of the Conway polynomial of the trefoil knot (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory#Knot_polynomials), but I got sidetracked by accidentally doing this:

[image: conway unknot]

(correction: they are all unKNOTS, not unlinks. and I apologize, yes this is MS paint.)

Surely I must have done something incorrectly?

Comment: You did - look closely at the arrows on your three (un)knots.  Each pair is facing in opposite directions around their respective links; they're not _orientations_ of the links.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is a crossing ($L_+$), I reversed the crossing to form $L_-$ , and I removed the crossing to form $L_0$. I don't see any links here.

Comment: The problem is that the arrows on your knot are supposed to give an _orientation_ - you're supposed to be able to follow them all the way around the knot.  (Imagine them as being sign pointers on a one-way street.)  The (un)knots you've drawn have their arrows pointing in different directions down the street.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that they had to be pointing in the same direction. This solves my problem! Thanks.

Comment: Note that this means that you can only use the skein relations 'one way' at a given crossing - there's only one position for a properly oriented crossing that makes the arrows line up correctly.